# Override application controller values

Tags: ember.js

I have an application that on many pages has a map.
This map needs to be removed/hidden on some pages.

I have some properties defined at the application controller level:

```
app.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  isAuthenticated: false,
  showMap: true
});
```

and I have another controller set for a route, let's say :

```
app.RegisterController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  showMap: false
});
```

In the ui the application controller properties are taken in consideration.
I would like to override the usage of the property from the application controller and take in consideration the value from the controller set for the current route.

Any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember provides a fairly comprehensive set of [computed property helpers](http://emberjs.com/api/) that can be used to combine properties. Combined with the [controller needs](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/) system which allows access to other controllers, these can be used to create a computed property that takes into account a property from the `applicationController` and the local controller:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  showMap: true
});

App.ChildController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['application'],
  showMap: false,
  combinedShowMap: Ember.computed.and('controllers.application.showMap', 'showMap')
});
```

This example creates a computed property, `combinedShowMap` that is the boolean `AND` operation of the `applicationController`'s `showMap` and the `childController`'s `showMap`.

[JSBin example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/UsiyEWiM/5/edit)

Comment: Is there another way that I can maybe lavage the route model so I don't have to do this dependencies between controllers ?

Comment: can you update your question with more details? I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do. Better yet, can you make an example jsbin? http://emberjs.jsbin.com/